# Заполнить np.array одинаковым элементом

Tags: python, numpy

Здравствуйте, интересует как забить список одним элементом в Numpy, google ответа не нашел. Подобная реализация работает, но хотелось бы знать как сделать это средствами Numpy.

```
X = np.linspace(-2, 2, 7)

list_y = [X.mean() ** 3]*len(X) 
y = np.array(list_X)
```

Comment: [`np.full(длина, значение)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
X = np.linspace(-2, 2, 7)

y = np.full(len(X), X.mean())
print(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
X = np.zeros((3,3))
X[:]=123
print(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([6,7,8])
arr[...] = 8
```

Все содержимое заполниться восьмерками.
Такой способ применим к массивам любой размерности.